# use super.paintComponent(g) or getGraphics() in java

Tags: java, graphics, 2d

i' m little bit confused about few things:

***Example code,that shows my problem,this isn't compilable***

```
// image
private BufferedImage image;
private Graphics2D graphic;
private changeImage;
. . .
//thread loop
while (running) {
   . . .
    render();
    Graphics showGraphic = getGraphics();
    showGraphic.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    showGraphic.dispose();
    }
 public void render(){
     if(changeImage == 1)
     graphic.drawImage(ImageLoader.TREE, 0, 0, null);
     else if(changeImage == 2){
     graphic.drawImage(ImageLoader.HOUSE, 0, 0, null);
      . . .
     graphic.fillRect(50,60,30,40);
     }
}
```

I create an global object  `Graphic2D` and i draw things in  `render()`, I do not call `repaint()` inside the game loop, **is it good practice to do this?**

Should I use `repaint()` inside my loop , and the `paintComponent()` function ?

one other thing, how `graphic.dispose()` works correctly? , because trying to remove this line of code, nothing happens.

*I understand how  works dispose() according to java docs*, ***but I have not noticed any differences with dispose() or without.***

my program runs very well, but i have this dubts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it good practice to do this

No, this is actually incredibly horrible and error prone.  This assumes that this is the  `Component#getGraphics` method.  The problem is Swing uses a passive rendering algorithm, that is, Swing decides when and what should be repainted and does this for optimisation reasons.

This means updates are not regular, which really helps when doing animation, and can happen at any time for any number reasons, many of which you simply don't and can't control.

For these reasons, painting should be done within one of the paint methods, preferably, `paintComponent` of a `JComponent` based class.  This way, when Swing decides to do a repaint, one, you know about it and can update the output accordingly, and two, it won't clear what you have previously painted to it using `getGraphics` which could cause flickering...

You are also running into potential threading issues, as you thread is trying to paint to the `Graphics` context, so might the Event Dispatching Thread and that isn't going to end pretty...All painting should be done from within the context of the EDT (for component based painting)

You could try using a `BufferedStrategy`, which would give you direct control over the painting process, but this limits you to the AWT library.  Don't know if this is good or bad in your case.

> one other thing, how graphic.dispose() works correctly? , because
>   trying to remove this line of code, nothing happens.

`dispose` basically releases any native resources that the `Graphics` context might be holding.  General rule of thumb, if you didn't create, you don't dispose of it.

So if you use `Graphics#create` or `BufferedImage#createGraphics` to obtain a `Graphics` context, then you should call `dispose` when your done with it.

On some systems calling `dispose` on the `Grpahics` context used to perform painting of components (such as that passed to `paintComponent` or obtained from `getGraphcis`) can prevent further content from been painted.

Equally, not disposing of `Graphics` contexts that you have created can lead to memory leaks as they won't get garbage collected...

Comment: thanks for the answer, very complete! now i know that dispose() is usefull enough, but as i said i didn't see any differences.

Comment: @CiMat This would be for a number of reasons, as I said, on systems it can prevent further painting from occurring. What might be happening is the context is been refreshed each time you call `getGraphics`

Comment: uderstood,so it's a bad practise but if `getGraphics` refresh the context and other stuff, it's not so so bad :)

Comment: @CiMat On you current system, this is the way it might work, on a different platform, it might work differently, that fact is, it's inconsistent.  Basically, you're trying to blow water back up Niagara falls with a straw...It might look like it's working, but in the long run, you'll just get wet...

Answer (score 1):

There are many questions about "good" or "correct" painting in Swing, so this question could be considered as a duplicate, and I won't try to repeat here what should be read in context, for example, in the [Lesson about Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/).

However, to summarize the most important information short and concisely:

- You should **never** call `getGraphics` on a `Component`. It may return `null` or a `Graphics` object that is in any other way "invalid". It will fail in the one form or the other, sooner or later
- You should do all your painting operations in the `paintComponent` method (or in methods that are called from `paintComponent`), using the `Graphics` object that you receive there as an argument
- Whether or not you call the `Graphics#dispose` method may not make a difference that is "immediately" visible. You should **not** call it on the one that you received in the `paintComponent`. You should *only* call it on a `Graphics` object that you either obtained from a `BufferedImage`, or one that you created by calling `Graphics#create()`. When you do not call it, this *might* cause a memory leak that will only be noticed after the application has been running for a while.

Comment: `You should never call getGraphics` , believe me i didnt never get null graphic, my program works fine, but as you say it si a bad practice

Comment: @CiMat Start with https://www.google.com/search?q="getgraphics+returns+null" ;-) You might provoke it, e.g. by resizing your window while the application is running. But in any case: You should not do it, because it may cause arbitrary, hard-to-debug problems (a `NullPointerException` being by far the easiest one here - you immediately know what's wrong, although not necessarily how to solve it, regardless of the effort that this might cause when you have to do it later...)

Comment: @CiMat Marco13 is correct, if the component hasn't been realised (added to a container whose parent window is visible), `getGraphics` will return `null`.  The fact that you haven't experienced this problem is simply a fluke